# how to set up parallel testing in maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests, maven-surefire-plugin

all tests run instantly and load the computer

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*CucumberRegressionRunner.java</include>
        </includes>
        <parallel>all</parallel>
        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
        <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
        <forkCount>2.5c</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <threadCount>2</threadCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

i want to run not all package, i need to run only 2-5 tests in parallel

Answer (score 1):

As the answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811430/exclude-specific-tests-from-being-run-in-parallel-in-junit) describes, you can create an execution for the tests, that should run parallel and an execution for the tests, that should not run parallell.