# Some Junit Test cases are failing when running all test classes together but passing individually

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, junit

Some Junit Test cases are failing when running all test classes together but passing individually.

I am running maven 'mvn clean install' and I could see the following things.

1. One Junit test class (Test1.java) is failing but all other test classes are passing. But same failed test class Test1.java is passing if I run it separately. In both Eclipse (IDE) and command line I noticed the same.
2. If I commented out everything inside one test class (Test2.java) then Test1.java is working when I run all test cases together.

So Test1.java is failing because of Test2.java. But not sure what is the exact cause. I would appreciate if anybody can suggest the root cause. Thanks.

**Junit Test1.java :**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class Test1 {

        public static final String REST_API_URI = "/api/someurl/abc";

        @Autowired
        private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;
    
        private static final String SVC_QUAL_CHANGE_TOPIC = "tnco-svcqual-change";
    
        @ClassRule
        public static EmbeddedKafkaRule embeddedKafka = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1,
                true,
                1,
                SVC_QUAL_CHANGE_TOPIC);
        
        @BeforeClass
        public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws IOException {
            System.setProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", embeddedKafka.getEmbeddedKafka().getBrokersAsString());
        }
    
        @AfterClass
        public static void tearDownAfterClass() {
            System.clearProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers");
        }
    
        @Test
        public void testCreateCheckServiceQualification() {
          ...
          //some API test code which send msg to Kafka
        }   
    }
```

**Junit Test2.java :**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = { "alm.ishtar.security.enabled = false" })
public class Test2 {

    public static final String REST_API_URI = "/api/someurl/xyz";

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;
    
    private static final String MOI_CHANGE_TOPIC = "tnco-moi-change";
    
    @ClassRule
    public static EmbeddedKafkaRule embeddedKafka = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1,
            true,
            1,
            MOI_CHANGE_TOPIC);
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", embeddedKafka.getEmbeddedKafka().getBrokersAsString());
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() {
        System.clearProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers");
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateMoiPut() throws Exception {
      ...
      //some API test code which send msg to Kafka
    }
}
```

Getting the below error in the console at the time of test failure:

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic tnco-svcqual-change not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic tnco-svcqual-change not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:573)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:401)
```

Note : Test method calls REST API and inside the API implementation it is sending message to Kafka topic.

Comment: Can you provide an exception it is failing with?

Comment: Hi @SveKamenska, It is failing with HTTP 500 Internal Server error.

Comment: this is too general. In order to help, we need a stacktrace to see. Obviously, it happens because Test2 changes something Test1 relies on.

Comment: It could be `System.setProperty`

Comment: I'm removing the Kafka tag since it isn't clear how your tests use Kafka and the server error is clearly related to it

Comment: Hi @SveKamenska , I have now added the stacktrace in the original Post. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, Test method calls REST API and inside the API implementation it is sending message to Kafka topic.

Comment: @SuryaN can you log in your before and after class methods in both TC classes? Its likely there is a race condition, and since both depend on the same system prop, there may be a conflict.

Comment: Based on your error, when are you actually creating the topic? And on which Kafka broker? Is there a need to separate your test classes instead of using a shared broker?

Answer (score 1):

From the error you provided, it is obvious that you run tests **in parallel**.

And this is a **shared resource**: `System.setProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", embeddedKafka.getEmbeddedKafka().getBrokersAsString());`

I can assume that

1. Test1 gets executed, it creates and configures embeddedKafka with `SVC_QUAL_CHANGE_TOPIC`, and sets its address to the shared property `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers`.
2. Then Test2 gets executed, configures another embeddedKafka with `MOI_CHANGE_TOPIC` and now property `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` points to the second embeddedKafka.
3. Test method from Test1 is executed, reads property `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` and uses "wrong" embeddedKafka.

Solution would be to

1. Exclude tests which rely on the same resource (system property `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` in this case) from the parallel run. And run them consequentially. Like here [Exclude specific tests from being run in parallel in jUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811430/exclude-specific-tests-from-being-run-in-parallel-in-junit)
2. Combine both tests in one and configure embeddedKafka with both topics.

Note, that setting up embeddedKafka before each test (instead of before Class) won't help, as nothing prevents Test1.method1 from executing at the same time Test2.methodX changes the property.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestions. I will try this.

Comment: But the thing is, as per the maven plugin setting I could not see any parallel thing is mentioned for test cases in my project. So I was wondering why those test cases are running in parallel. As per the setting, Test cases will run Alphabetically. 
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

Comment: Can you add some sysout messages to see the actual test running order?